# AWS EventBridge filter with conditional OR patterns for OldImage

Tags: amazon-web-services, filter, amazon-dynamodb, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to filter a DynamoDB stream via EventBridge patterns, I would like to be able to filter based on a value in specific column that can change for two reasons:

1. A new row was inserted with the specific value I am looking for.
2. An existing role's value was changed to the desired value.

Any other changes should be ignored. I tried creating following filter:

```
{
  "eventName": ["INSERT", "MODIFY"],
  "dynamodb": {
    "NewImage": {
      "state": {
        "M": {
          "column": {
            "S": ["state1"]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "OldImage": {
      "state": {
        "M": {
          "column": {
            "S": [{
              "anything-but": ["state1"]
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This of course fails because create operations do not have OldImage entries. Looking at the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html#eb-filtering-complex-example-or) for conditional matches I then tried to add an $or statement with null and a valid OldImage entry but it it not considered to be a valid EventBridge:

```
"OldImage": {
 "$or" : [null, {....}]
}

Aside from simply creating a lambda that checks the OldImage vs the NewImage is there a way to achieve this via EventBridge filters?
```

Answer (score 0):

When you apply 2 filters together they become a Boolean AND expression. You want to acbibeia Boolean OR, so you should create 2 individual filters. You can attach up to 5 filters to a DynamoDB stream.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work

```
{"$or": [{
        "eventName": ["INSERT"],
        "dynamodb": {
            "NewImage": {
                "state": {
                    "M": {
                        "column": {
                            "S": ["state1"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "eventName": ["MODIFY"],
        "dynamodb": {
            "NewImage": {
                "state": {
                        "M": {
                            "column": {
                                "S": ["state1"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "OldImage": {
                "state": {
                        "M": {
                            "column": {
                                "S": [{"anything-but": ["state1"]}]
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```